# Scala: filter with different conditions specified by tuples in a set

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a RDD with it's field1 containing a drug name and field2 containing corresponding dosage of that drug.
I am trying to filter this RDD based on multiple criterion saved in a set of tuples, like:

```
val MyCriteria = Set(("drug a", ">", 1.2), ("drug b", ">=", 4.5), ("drug c", "<", 6.3))
```

I guess what I can do is something like:

```
val rslt = rdd.filter(x => MyCriteria.foreach(x.field1 == _._1 && x.field2 _._2 _._3))
```

But I don't know how to convert the 2nd element of the tuple (string) to actual operators that scala understands. It throws out an error message:

```
<console>:1: error: ')' expected but '.' found.
    val rslt = rdd.filter(x => MyCriteria.foreach(x.field1 == _._1 && x.field2 _._2 _._3))
                                                                                ^
```

Or what would be a better way to realize the filter?

Comment: If you use dataframe then you can use column expression to solve it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work like this, Scala string literal's won't be translated into operator. 
Instead you need to use function to compare values from RDD with filter results.

Please, see code example below:

```
type Compare[T : Numeric] = (T, T) => Boolean
type DoubleCompare = Compare[Double]
val > : DoubleCompare = _ > _
val < : DoubleCompare = _ < _
val >= : DoubleCompare = _ >= _

val myCriteria: Set[(String, DoubleCompare, Double)] = Set (
    ("drug a", > , 1.2),
    ("drug b", >=, 4.5),
    ("drug c", <,  6.3)
)

rdd.filter { x =>
    val fieldName = x.field1
    val fieldValue = x.field2
    myCriteria.foreach {
        case (filterFieldName, filter, filterValue) =>
            (fieldName == filterFieldName) && filter(fieldValue, filterValue)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I like this idea! Using data frame column expression will be far versatile.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use DataFrame instead of RDD then you can use the `where` with String expression which will handle all data types and you don't have to code for them.

```
    import spark.implicits._
    val df = spark.createDataset(Seq(("drug a",5),("drug b",4),("drug c",4))).toDF("drug","dose")
    val criteria = Set(("drug a", ">", 1.2), ("drug b", ">=", 4.5), ("drug c", "<", 6.3))

    df.show()

    val criteriaExp = criteria.foldLeft(""){(cstr, cset)=>
      if(cstr == "")
        s"(drug = '${cset._1}' and dose ${cset._2} ${cset._3})"
      else
        s"$cstr or (drug = '${cset._1}' and dose ${cset._2} ${cset._3})"
    }

    println(criteriaExp)
    df.where(criteriaExp).show()
```

Result

```
+------+----+
|  drug|dose|
+------+----+
|drug a|   5|
|drug b|   4|
|drug c|   4|
+------+----+

criteria string - (drug = 'drug a' and dose > 1.2) or (drug = 'drug b' and dose >= 4.5) or (drug = 'drug c' and dose < 6.3)

+------+----+
|  drug|dose|
+------+----+
|drug a|   5|
|drug c|   4|
+------+----+
```